# Using the respond_to method to render a js.erb partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, controller, partial-views

I have a feature where users like/unlike and dislike/undislike dishes. This is how I initially have my actions setup:

**Dishes Controller**

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController
  def like
    @dish.liked_by current_user
  end

  def dislike
    @dish.disliked_by current_user
  end
  ...
end
```

Considering the `js.erb` templates for each template are completely identical I wanted to create just one shared partial that each could use:

**Original Setup**

```
# like.js.erb, unlike.js.erb,dislike.js.erb,undislike.js.erb

$(".restaurant__dish-vote--<%= @dish.modifier_class %>").html('<%= escape_javascript(render "restaurants/menu_partials/dish_votes", dish: @dish) %>');
```

**New Setup**

```
# shared/_vote.js.erb

$(".restaurant__dish-vote--<%= @dish.modifier_class %>").html('<%= escape_javascript(render "restaurants/menu_partials/dish_votes", dish: @dish) %>');
```

Now I'm trying to refactor my controller to reflect these changes but the ajax functionality doesn't seem to work with the following:

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController
  def like
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render partial: "dishes/shared/vote.js.erb" }
    end

    @dish.liked_by current_user
  end
end
```

The action completes but the changes on the user-facing side are only reflected upon refresh. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should call @dish.liked_by current_user before render partial

Comment: Ah that did the trick. Feel free to post that as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call `@dish.liked_by current_user` before `render partial: "dishes/shared/vote.js.erb"`. The problem is that `@dish` is not updated yet.