# Putting a respond_to method inside a before_action callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, callback, controller

I guess you can consider this a continuation from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790349/using-the-respond-to-method-to-render-a-js-erb-partial). Basically I'm rendering a `js.erb` partial which enables ajax functionality to like/dislike a restaurant dish. I have four actions that render this partial:

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController
  def like
    @dish.liked_by current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render partial: "dishes/shared/vote.js.erb" }
    end
  end

  def unlike
    @dish.unliked_by current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render partial: "dishes/shared/vote.js.erb" }
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

To DRY this up I planned to put the `respond_to` method inside of a `before_action` callback:

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :render_vote_partial
  ...
  private
    ...
    def render_vote_partial
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render partial: "dishes/shared/vote.js.erb" }
      end
    end
end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't render the partial at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dry up the respond_to, just stick it in a method (like you have already) and call that method after each action.

Instead of

```
before_action :render_vote_partial
```

just do do:

```
def like
  # do your work here ...

  render_vote_partial
end

def unlike
  # do your work here ...

  render_vote_partial
end
```

Comment: Is this not the equivalent of what the `before_action` does?

Comment: before_actions happen before you do you work. So If I did my work after render_vote_partial was called that would be teh same.

Steps of execution are: 1) BeforeAction 2) like method

Comment: I was also thinking that an `after_action` callback would suffice but it didn't work at all.

Comment: You're right about the after_action not working. Just call the function that does the render. While its not super DRY it is DRY in that your rendering only has to be changed in one place to affect all your actions.